# Wait until cubevalues have loaded data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with many cells that use `CUBEVALUE` to load data. These cubevalues point to some common cells, which are the main parameters for the cubevalue query. With my VBA script, I change these common parameters and hence all the cubevalues are reevaluated. I want to wait until all the cubevalues are reevaluated. How can I do that?

I tried this:

```vb
Sub WaitUntilCalculationDone()
    Dim waittime As Integer
    waittime = 0
    
    Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
        waittime = waittime + 2
    Loop
    
    Debug.Print "waited " & CStr(waittime)
End Sub
```

This code waits for the `Application.CalculationState` to change to `xlDone` before finishing the script. However, it's not working as expected. How can I modify this code to wait until all the cubevalues are reevaluated? This question is related to my previous question: [Saving pomegranate Bayesian Network models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473292/how-to-update-all-cubevalue-functions-after-changing-olap-cube-connection-string)

Comment: You might need to use `DoEvents` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277034/wait-until-application-calculate-has-finished

Comment: The link you provided me helped me. DoEvents was not successful, but application.wait was the right thing to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you handle the application's `AfterCalculate` event?

You create a class (Insert->Class Module) which stores an instance of the Application (in this example, I've called the class *clsApp*):

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mApp As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub mApp_AfterCalculate()
    MsgBox "After calculation"
End Sub
```

And in your module, instance the class:

```
Option Explicit
Private mApp As clsApp

Public Sub RunMe()
    Set mApp = New clsApp
End Sub
```